# Bing Map Pushpin - How to add clustering layer on Bing Map with custom data (co-ordinates) using Bing Maps V8 interactive SDK?

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I found an official article which is showing, how to add clustering layer to Map but that example  takes input from a **TestDataGenerator** function.I don't know how to pass my information so that map will generate pushpin based on my data.

[Bing Map Official Article on "Add clustering layer to map"](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#clusteringMeanAverage+JS)

```
<div id='printoutPanel'></div>
        <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function loadMapScenario() {
                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(39.393486, -98.100769),
                    zoom: 3
                });
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Clustering', function () {
                    // Creating sample Pushpin data within map view
                    var pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(1000, map.getBounds());
                    var clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pushpins, { gridSize: 100 });
                    map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
```

Please visit the above link if anything is un-clear.

Answer (score 0):

The test data generator returns an array of pushpins. Simply loop through your custom data and create an array of pushpins and then pass that into the clustering layer.

Comment: Thank you  for your response. Can you please give me  simple code about what kind of data I can  put inside pushpin array. I want generate pushpin using longitude and longitude.

Comment: There are a ton of samples and documentation on this: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#addDefaultPushpin+JS

Comment: No, there aren't tons of samples, as a matter of fact very few and repetitive. The only example for clustering uses random generation of pushpins, when trying to make it work with custom pushpins I cannot resolve how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First add a new  to your page with id and style display:none
add a gridview to this div
Bind your data to this gridview

Code Sample to bind data to map - works in ie  - recently started having issues in Edge and Firefor - works on Safari

Issues seem to be related to attempts to add second cluster layer

Comments appreciated

```
function loadMap() {
                var MaxLat = 0;
                var MinLon = 0;
                var MinLat = 0;
                var MaxLon = 0;
                var MLon = 0;
                var MLat = 0;
                var c;
                var Val2;
                var Val3;
                var Lat;
                var Lon;
                var Val1;
                var PPO;
                var Val4;
                var Val5;



                if (typeof GVBounds !== "undefined" && GVBounds !== null) {
                    var Mcell = GVBounds.rows[1].cells;
                    MaxLat = Mcell(0).innerHTML;
                    MinLon = Mcell(1).innerHTML;
                    MinLat = Mcell(2).innerHTML;
                    MaxLon = Mcell(3).innerHTML;
                    MLat = Mcell(4).innerHTML;
                    MLon = Mcell(5).innerHTML;
                }

                var map;
                var Rec = MaxLat + "," + MinLon + "," + MinLat + "," + MaxLon
                var box = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromString(Rec);

                //var PPCDr = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
                //var PPCPU = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
                //var PPCD = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
                //var PPC = []
                var pinDr;
                var pinPU;
                var pinD;

                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    //center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(MLat, MLon)
                }
                );

                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {

                    var Pins = [];

                    Pins = GetPins();

                    //Create a ClusterLayer and add it to the map.
                    clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(Pins, { gridSize: 10 });

                    map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
                });


                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {

                    var DrPins = [];

                    DrPins = GetDrPins();

                    //Create a ClusterLayer and add it to the map.
                    DrclusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(DrPins, { gridSize: 1 });

                    map.layers.insert(DrclusterLayer);
                });

                map.setView({ bounds: box, padding: 20 });

            }
```

RayD